# using Bootstrap3 form in laravel5.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.1

I am trying to make a form using bootstrap3 in laravel5.1 so that I can get values from user and store it on the database and want to redirect the same page.
here is the form part of my code --

```
<div class="row">
        <form action="{{url('fastshops/menu')}} " method="post" role="form">
            <legend>ADD NEW ITEM</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for=""></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemID" id="" placeholder="Item ID...">
                <label for=""></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemName" id="" placeholder="Item Name...">
                <label for=""></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SellPrice" id="" placeholder="Sell Price...">
                <label for=""></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NetPrice" id="" placeholder="Net Price...">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

but this part `action="{{url('fastshops/menu')}}` is not working ! If I click on the submit button I am having TokenMismatchException ! please help me out.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this 
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}"/>` or
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>` 
inside your form.
Laravel 5 automatically check for CSRF on all Post request for all the routes. Read the docs, they are pretty self explainatory